# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB, cant save data

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder

can anyone help me?

i have create table with 2 column and one of it was CLOB datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE "OFFTEST"."COMMENT_TEST" 
(   "CMNT" CLOB, 
    "ID_COM" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE)
```

This is my syntax in powerbuilder.net to save insert data into database

```
dw_comments.Modify("DataWindow.Table.Insert='INSERT INTO COMMENT_TEST(CMNT, ID_COM) VALUES (:1, :2 )'")
```

but why this error occurred, i jusr put a few off data on it????

Thanks for your precious time :
[image]

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: Are your variables in order like first variable is clob and second variable is int?

Comment: In Powerbuilder you are able to run SQL statment from the Powerscript. Have you tried run this insert script outside the datawindow in Powerscript? Has it the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The top level problem is that you're trying to use a DataWindow attribute for the wrong purposes. "DataWindow.Table.Insert" by itself isn't an attribute, but the "DataWindow.Table.Insert.*" attributes are to describe the *stored procedure* insert method for the DataWindow. INSERT SQL command syntax is generated automatically by the DataWindow (based on various update properties in the DataWindow), and aren't declared explicitly like this.

However, you have a more basic problem, in that the DataWindow is not designed to handle updates to large binary data types directly like this. If your columns remain under 32K, people have gotten away with updating large columns with the generated INSERT/UPDATE statements, but once you go over 32K, you run into problems. There are OLE controls that might do updates (e.g. rich text edit style), but they do it under a separate transaction from the rest of the DataWindow. There's also PowerScript commands like INSERT/UPDATEBLOB that might become part of your solution. It depends on what you're doing, and that's not clear from what you've told us so far.

Good luck,

Terry.